# [OpenCV]how to fix contours to rectangle?

Tags: opencv

## Note

I'm new to OpenCV(or computer vision), so it would be very helpful just to tell me the search query!

## What I want to ask

I want to write a program that extract the business cards from pictures.
I was able to extract a rough outline, but reflected light becomes noise and I can't extract an accurate outline. Please tell me your idea.

### image(raw data)

[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD1BU.jpg)

### output

[output data(rough outline)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEpS4.png)

### code

```
import math
import itertools
from glob import glob

import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

%matplotlib inline

def read_images():
    "read image data from data directory"
    names = glob('data/*.jpg')
    names.sort()
    return map(lambda name: cv2.imread(name), names)

def blur(img):
    "apply blur"
    return cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (25, 25), 0)

def show_images(images, column, color_type=cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB):
    "plot images with matplotlib"
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10), dpi=150)
    for n, img in zip(range(len(images)), images):
        p = plt.subplot(math.ceil(len(images) / column), column, n + 1)
        p.axis('off')
        if color_type is None:
            p.imshow(img)
        else:
            p.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, color_type))
    plt.show()

def detect_background_color(img):
    "detect background color"
    # Assume that the perimeter is all background
    height, width, *_ = img.shape
    background_colors = np.concatenate([
        img[5:height-5, 5],       img[5, 5:width-5],
        img[5:height-5, width-5], img[height-5, 5:width-5]
    ])
    background_colors = background_colors.astype(np.float32)

    # Assume that the background color is only one.
    K = 2
    iter_flg = cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER
    _, labels, centers = cv2.kmeans(
        background_colors, K, None, (iter_flg, 10, 1.0), 10,
        cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

    cnt1 = len(labels[labels==0])
    cnt2 = len(labels[labels==1])
    return centers[0] if cnt1 > cnt2 else centers[1]

def scale(img):
    bg = detect_background_color(img)
    return np.fix(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(img - bg), axis=2)) / 1.732).astype(np.uint8)

def binarize(img):
    th, bit = cv2.threshold(img, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    return bit

binarized = [binarize(scale(blur(img))) for img in read_images()]
show_images(binarized, 4, None)
```

Comment: Did you try using a non-reflective background?

Comment: The image is input by the user, so I don't have permission to select a background.

Comment: if you have by any chance the possibility to interact with the user, I think explaining how to take the picture (a couple of hints about avoiding reflections) before they upload it would save you lots of trouble trying to eliminate the reflections.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to apply morphology try cv2.erode and then cv2 dilate operations.
The first will remove regions smaller than erode kernel size, the second will restore initial size of large blob. You need to apply the same size kernels for both operations.
[morphology](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm).

Check also this: [medium article](https://medium.com/cashify-engineering/improve-accuracy-of-ocr-using-image-preprocessing-8df29ec3a033)

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't solved.I think you said apply function like this.

1. apply `cv2.erode`. this makes area "skinny".
2. apply `cv2.dilate`. this makes area "fat".

I think I can remove small noise, but not large noise (reflected light, etc.). Is this correct?

Comment: No, it will keep only large solid block. Erosion will remove all "thin" artifacrs, like points, thin lines, small regions. even if they are connenced to "main" blob. After erosion large region will become a little bit smaller, as erotion will "eat" some pixrls from edges. To restore the initial size, we need to apply dilation, it will return eaten pixeld back. And will fill grown by erosion holes. Antway card area is much larger than artifacts and it looks contigous. Try large kernel sizes.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I understood. The value of parameter was the problem. It's a pity that this issue wasn't solved, but this experience seems to be useful for another issue.

Comment: Glad it was useful )